# '[(ngModel)]' for field of object form inside another object

Tags: angular, forms, object, templates, structure

I am trying to do something that I am not sure if it is possible.
For an Angular form I have and object like this:

```
export class NewUserRegisterModelDTO{
    userData:UserDetailModelDTO;
    roles:RoleModelDTO[];
    ownerData:OwnerDetailDTO;
}
```

```
export class UserDetailModelDTO {
    email:string;
    username:string;
    password:string;
    repeatPassword: string;
}
```

In my HTML form I have something like that:

```
<form class="form" #newUser="ngForm" action="" method="post">

    <h2 class="text-info">New User</h2>
    <hr>

    <div class="mr-10 ml-10">
        <h4 class="text-info mt-3">Login Info</h4>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="text-info">Email</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeHolder="email" [ngClass]="{'formInputError': ((email.errors?.minlength || email.errors?.required)) && email.touched}" [(ngModel)]="newUser.userData.email" required #email="ngModel">
                    <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.errors?.required" class="form-control-feedback mt-2 ml-2">Email required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

its not the full HTML because it is so big. but as you can see, the point is this tag: `[(ngModel)]="newUser.userData.email"`

In my TS file i have the following:

```
export class NewUserComponent {

  public newUser : NewUserRegisterModelDTO;
  loadingUsernameCheck: boolean = false;
  usernameExist : boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService : AuthService, private userService: UserService) { 
    this.newUser = new NewUserRegisterModelDTO();
    this.newUser.userData = new UserDetailModelDTO();
    this.newUser.ownerData = new OwnerDetailDTO();
    console.log(this.newUser);
  }
```

Just when i load the page i have the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewUserComponent.html:13)

It is possible to declare an [(ngModel)] like that? or do I have to create an Object with all independent fields and then contruct the NewUserRegisterModelDTO?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModel` binding is supposed to refer to the `newUser` property of the component class:

```
public newUser : NewUserRegisterModelDTO;

[(ngModel)]="newUser.userData.email"
```

but you also define a `newUser` [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) in your template:

```
<form #newUser="ngForm" ... >
```

and `ngModel` uses that variable instead of the class property. And since `ngForm` does not have the `userData` property, trying to access `newUser.userData.email` causes a runtime error.

Rename the template reference variable (and adjust the code that actually refers to it) and the `ngModel` binding should work fine:

```
<form #newUserForm="ngForm" ... >
```

Comment: It works Thanks. But I dont have understand it very well. I will try to learn that witl the official documentation

Comment: I recommend reading [this documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). It has a section about [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) but the whole page is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Write a constructor for NewUserRegisterModelDTO :

```
export class NewUserRegisterModelDTO{
    userData:UserDetailModelDTO;
    roles:RoleModelDTO[];
    ownerData:OwnerDetailDTO;
    constructor(){
    this.userData = new UserDetailModelDTO();
    this.roles = [];
    this.ownerData = new OwnerDetailDTO();
    }
}
```

then use this in ts file :

```
  public newUser : NewUserRegisterModelDTO = new NewUserRegisterModelDTO ();
```

also you must write constructor for UserDetailModelDTO and OwnerDetailDTO

Answer (score 0):

You should create constructor both your models.

For example

```
export class NewUserRegisterModelDTO{
    userData:UserDetailModelDTO;
    roles:RoleModelDTO[];
    ownerData:OwnerDetailDTO;
    constructor(){
       this.userData =new UserDetailModelDTO();
    }
}

export class UserDetailModelDTO {
    email:string;
    username:string;
    password:string;
    repeatPassword: string;
    constructor(){
      this.email = null;
    }
}
```

Please examine [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwn3wq)

Comment: I have add a picture creating all constructor with null and default value and I have the same error. I don't understand why